# table data renders only by adding hashtag at the end of address Vue 3

Tags: api, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router, router

I'm trying to render data to a table, I recieve the data in console but nothing in the table unless I add a # to the end of address like:

```
http://localhost:81/realstate#
```

or if i make a change in table code and it renders right away.

- I also added WebHistory to router and works fine with every other pages. the only problem is for rendering data of this page.
  Code:
  [image]

Methods:

```
async getProperty() {
  await this.$store.dispatch("axiosGet",
      {url: 'folder/api/properties'}).then(response => {
    if (response.status === 'error') return
    this.propertyList = response.data.data.data
    if (!response.data.data.data.length) {
      this.propertyList = 0
    }
    console.log(response.data.data.data)
  })
},
```

the router:

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'

const routes = [
{path: '/realstate', name: 'RealState', component: RealState},

]
const router = createRouter({history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL), routes, linkActiveClass: 'active'})
```

Axios Get in Store:

```
const baseURL = process.env.VUE_APP_REST_API
const token = localStorage.getItem('token') ? localStorage.getItem('token'): ''
state: { token}, getters: { token: state => state.token
async axiosGet({ dispatch }, {url}) {

  dispatch('checkAxiosConfig')
  let response

  await axios.get(url, {headers: {
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
     }})
      .then((res) => {response = {status: 'success', data: res}})
      .catch(error => {response = {status: 'error', data: error}})
  if (response.status === 'error') dispatch('errorHandler', response)
  return response
},
```

in Mutations there's only:

```
 mutations: {
toggleConfigurator(state) {
  state.showConfig = !state.showConfig
},
navbarMinimize(state) {
  const sidenav_show = document.querySelector('.g-sidenav-show')
  if (sidenav_show.classList.contains('g-sidenav-hidden')) {
    sidenav_show.classList.remove('g-sidenav-hidden')
    sidenav_show.classList.add('g-sidenav-pinned')
    state.isPinned = true
  } else {
    sidenav_show.classList.add('g-sidenav-hidden')
    sidenav_show.classList.remove('g-sidenav-pinned')
    state.isPinned = false
  }
},
sidebarType(state, payload) {
  state.sidebarType = payload
},
navbarFixed(state) {
  state.isNavFixed = state.isNavFixed === false
}
```

},

Comment: Please do not use screenshots, but paste the code in as text.

Comment: the code will not be shown as a table that's why I've changed it to screenshot

Comment: But that's a screenshot of your code editor, isn't it, not of the browser rendering it. But anyway, can you also provide the relevant store action and mutations that are called?

Comment: I just updated it

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things in your code that are a bit odd:

You combine [`async/await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/async_function#examples) with [`.then/.catch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises). Although both are valid ways to handle promises, you should not combine them. So you should choose for an approach like:

```
const response = await getDataFunction();
if (response.success) {...}
```

Or:

```
getDataFunction().then(response => {...}).catch(err => {...})
```

Secondly, you are using are using dispatch to call an action in the store, which you expect to return data in `response`. This is not a preferred way to use the store. You should dispatch the **action**, store the data as **state** through a **mutation** and then get the data from the store. Probably by using a computed property. [You can read about the Vuex pattern here.](https://medium.com/vue-mastery/vuex-explained-visually-f17c8c76d6c4)

If you do not need the data as application state, you should do the Axios call directly from your component.

There is too much refactoring to do to make it possible for me to give you an example of working code, but I hope this helps you in the right direction.